# Mixed Content, This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS , Laravel

Tags: laravel, mixed-content, laravel-7

I have this error one production env. only on some routes, I see no difference between the routes that works and the few of them that don't work. All my routes are in web.php, and in front I try to access via Vuejs/Axios.
Also, the both url from error when I try to access them I get to https://, even if I try http:// , I get redirect to https.

What I tried till now.

**.env**

```
APP_URL=https://my.url
```

**web.php**

```
URL::forceScheme('https');  //at the top of the file
```

**App/Providers/AppServiceProvider**

```
public function boot()
{
    URL::forceScheme('https');
}
```

**Also:**

```
composer dump-autoload
php artisan cache:clear
php artisan config:clear
php artisan view:clear
php artisan route:clear
php artisan config:cache
npm run prod
```

Comment: can you share a screenshot ?

Comment: I am not sure, screenshot of what? But I fix the problem, thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a strange solution.

I changed the route name from `random_question` to `random`, also the controller method name that was `show` to `random` and works.

Comment: Then it may be cache issue. Your routes were not properly cached.